# How can I check user input if equal to character of array

Tags: java, arrays

```
   while(...) {
        if (!(input >= 'A' && input <= 'Z')){
                System.out.println("Invalid input:" + input);}
        else {
            for (int i=0 ; i<randomWordToGuess.length ; i++) {
                if(randomWordToGuess[i] == input ) {
                   playerGuess[i] = input;
                }
            }
        }
  }
```

How can I check if user input is equal to character of array
like:

1. if user enters 'B', suppose array have B so store it into `playerGuess[i]`
2. if user enter 'F', suppose this is not in the array so store it into `invalidGuess[i]`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use Java Set instead of array the code will be faster and more efficient because the complexity of searching on Array is O(N) but in Hash set that use Read-Balck tree is O(log(n)), please read more about [Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) and [HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html?is-external=true)

```
    Set<Character> randomWordToGuess = new HashSet<>();
    Set<Character> playerGuess = new HashSet<>();
    ....// fill randomWordToGuess Set

    while(...){

        if (!(input >= 'A' && input <= 'Z')){
            System.out.println("Invalid input:" + input);}

        else if (!randomWordToGuess.contains(input)) {
                playerGuess .add(input)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

With an array, you don't have a straight way but you don' have really the choice as the input letter may appear multiple times and at any location of the word to guess and you have to mach all of them.

So you should iterate on elements  and compare each one with the input until a matching or the last element.

```
for (int i=0 ; i<randomWordToGuess.length ; i++){
     if(randomWordToGuess[i] == input ) {
           playerGuess[i] = input;
           break;               
      }
     invalidGuess[i] = input;
}
```

But you could use a `Set` that contains the letter to guess to make a first check and avoid iterating if no matching for a letter.